# What does the red X mean?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I was playing some quick match multiplayer and I noticed one of the players (who was not ready, and was taking a long time) had a red X on his display.
What does it mean?
[image]

Comment: btw, the X, arrow and box was all red, even when I had a different player selected.

Comment: Should the [tag:multiplayer] tag be added here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the "Vote to Kick" icon.

It's a very literal case of "Three strikes and you're out".

Comment: To kick someone press the y button incase you didn't know that. Sometimes people join games just to troll people by not being ready.