# Vote kick after the game has started

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I know you can [vote to kick people before starting a game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55009/4012) but is this possible after a game has already started? Specifically kicking people for being AFK unless there is a time out type thing for inactive players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't kick people while in the game, you can only kick in the lobby. There's really nothing you can do to prevent players from doing something stupid or going AFK in the game except to only play private games.

Comment: More importantly you can't mute them...infuriating

Comment: @Rarity You can mute them on the xbox using the standard xbox live mute player options.